# Django noreversematch for class based views

Tags: django

I have this view:

```
class ProfileView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'home/profile.html'
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = '/'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.request.user
```

and urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.HomeView.as_view(), name="index"),
    url(r'^me/$', login_required(views.ProfileView.as_view()), name="me"),
)
```

main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', include('demo.apps.home.urls', namespace="home")),
)
```

When I try to reverse it in template:

```
<a href="{% url 'home:me' %}">My Profile</a>
```

I get the `NoReverseMatch` error:

```
Reverse for 'me' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'$me']
```

Comment: Is this your main `urls.py`, or is it included from another module's `urlpatterns`?

Comment: included from the main, in my project I have defined namespace='home' but in this question I have taken it out for simplicity

Comment: Please add the contents of your main `urls.py` file to your question, at least the rule where you include this `urls.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main `urls.py` only includes your `demo.apps.home.urls` for *empty URLs* (as that's what `^$` matches). You need to remove at least the final `$`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^', include('demo.apps.home.urls', namespace="home")),
)
```

Comment: I think it would be much easier for me to find out the problem if the error message didn't include `1 pattern(s) tried: [u'$me']`

Comment: That error message is precisely what directed me to ask if you're including your `urls.py` from another module — that leading `$` had to come from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you include url by using namespace, you have to use the namespace in the url tag (or reverse function) too:

```
<a href="{% url 'home:me' %}">My Profile</a>
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, please see my latest update, I had taken out the main urls.py for simplicity in this question.